# How to dispaly the logo icon at the center for all device width?

Tags: html, css

I have the following Html Markup in my website:

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="flyoutMenuButtons visible-phone">
        <a href="#navigation" class="open-menu"><i class="icon-reorder icon-3x"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="close-menu"><i class="icon-reorder icon-3x"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div id="logo_and_search">
        <a id="logo" href="/" title="abc">
            <img src="abc.png" height="40" width="136">
        </a>                  
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like the logo to be diaplayed in center for all device widths.
What style shall I apply to the "#logo" element in order make it display in center for all devices other than desktops and tablets?

Comment: can you give some code in fiddle with your css

Comment: `#logo_and_search {text-align: center;}` is all you need

Comment: and `#logo {margin: auto}` ;)

Comment: Op is asking: "for all devices **other than** desktops and tablets". The answers posted will work on all devices ;)

Comment: Funny!! want verticaly center or horizontaly center?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use like this:

```
a#logo{
display: block;
text-align: center;
}
a#logo img{
display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this but if you give fiddle example it be fine

```
#logo_and_search {
width:100%;
}

#logo {
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#logo {
    display: block;
    width:136px; /* the same as the logo*/
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```